# lambda signature for_each + unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
  std::unordered_map<string, int> hash {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};

  // CaseA(NO-ERROR)
  std::for_each(hash.begin(), hash.end(),
    [](const std::pair<string, int>& p) {
      std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << endl;
    }
  );

  // CaseB(NO-ERROR)
  std::for_each(hash.begin(), hash.end(),
    [](const std::pair<string, int> p) {
      std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << endl;
    }
  );

  // CaseC(NO-ERROR)
  std::for_each(hash.begin(), hash.end(),
    [](std::pair<string, int> p) {
      std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << endl;
    }
  );

  // CaseD(ERROR)
  std::for_each(hash.begin(), hash.end(),
    [](std::pair<string, int>& p) {
      std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << endl;
    }
  );

}
```

Q1> **Why CaseD is wrong?**

Q2> **Is it true that CaseA is the recommended way?**

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `value_type` for a `std::unordered_map<K,V>` is `std::pair<const K,V>` (note the `const`). 
You cannot bind a reference of type `std::pair<K,V>` to an object of type `std::pair<const K,V>`. You should use `std::unordered_map<K,V>::value_type` instead of trying to spell the name of the type directly, as that will make sure that you don't get it wrong.

In case you wonder, case C works as there is a constructor that enables the conversion of the types, so that `p` will be a copy of the value in the `std::unordered_map`.

The *recommended* way for a lambda that is not meant to modify the elements in the container would be:

```
[](const std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::value_type& p)
```

In the first 3 cases in the question a copy of the element is done (performance hit). From the point of view of the caller, cases B and C are the same (in a function, the top level qualifier is dropped), but from the point of view of the definition of the lambda case B will ensure that you don't attempt to modify the argument (which is itself a copy of the source)

Comment: In his case, he likely wants `std::unordered_map<K,V>::value_type &`, to avoid copies

Comment: @DaveS: Most probably `const std::unordered_map<K,V>::value_type&` to avoid copies and inhibit erroneously modifying the contents of the container

Comment: Q1> In general, is it true that the passed-in parameter to lambda expression is the Container::value_type? Q2> "In the first 3 cases in the question a copy of the element is done ". Is it because that I use `pair<std::string,int>` instead of `pair<const std::string, int>`?

Comment: don't you need `const typename std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::value_type& p` here?

Comment: @Walter, if any of `string` or `int` is undefined, then typename is must

Comment: @q0987: Q1> lambdas have many uses, in this particular case where you want to apply the lambda to the elements in a container `value_type` *is* the type of those elements. Q2> Yes, the copy in case A is done because the types don't match, and that means that the reference in the lambda argument cannot be bound to the element, so it must copy and then bind the reference (in cases B and C the copy is there because you pass by value).

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your container is full of `std::pair<const string, int>`.  For case 1 through 3, the `std::pair<const string, int>` in the container can be converted to a `std::pair<string, int>` implicitly, and then that temporary passed to your lambda.

The recommended way in C++11 to do something non-mutating for each element of a container is:

```
for( auto const& p: hash ) {
  std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << endl;
}
```

which is less verbose, and doesn't violate DRY.  Prefer container-based iteration instead of iterator-based iteration when it makes sense.

Between container-based `std::` algorithms and `auto` typed lambdas, using the `std::` algorithms is going to become more tempting again in a version or two of C++.  Even then, unless you are abstracting over the kind of algorithm you are using your lambda on, `for_each` is now quite questionable, because we have a first-class language feature that does what `for_each` does.